# Issue with ColdFusion 2016 CFGrid update function

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

This has worked fine for many versions prior. After update to ColdFusion 2016, `cfgrid` produces an error when trying to update a cell like active status from 2 to 3 for an item.

User updates the cell and hits enter, then refreshes the grid and sees their change is not stored. The `cfdebug` error from AJAX logger is `cfgridchanged is undefined`. Any suggestions on how to make this work in ColdFusion 2016?

```
<cfgrid name="modify_pids" 
    height=525
    autowidth="yes"
    width=1040
    vspace=10
    selectmode="edit"
    insert="No"
    delete="No"        
    format="html"
    selectonload = "no"
    striperows = "yes"
    selectcolor="CDE6F3"
    preservePageOnSort="Yes"
    pagesize=100
    sort=true
    onChange="cfc:functions_pids.updatePID({cfgridaction},{cfgridrow},                        {cfgridchanged}, '#getcurruser.uid#')"
    bind="cfc:functions_pids.getPIDS({cfgridpage},{cfgridpagesize},    {cfgridsortcolumn},{cfgridsortdirection}, '#mygridsortcolumn#', searchPID(),     searchDESC(), searchSTAT(), searchMOQ(), searchCOST(), searchUNIT(),     searchMODBY(), searchMODDATE() )">

<cfgridcolumn name="PID_ID"
        header="PID"
        width=40
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="No">

   <cfgridcolumn name="Description"
        header="Description"
        width=150
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="Yes">

    <cfgridcolumn name="Active_Status"
        header="Status<br>Active=1,3<br>Inactive=2"
        width=35
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="Yes"
        display="yes">  

    <cfgridcolumn name="MOQ"
        header="MOQ"
        width=20
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="Yes">

     <cfgridcolumn name="COST"
        header="Cost"
        width=40
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="Yes">

     <cfgridcolumn name="UNIT"
        header="Unit"
        width=40
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="Yes">

    <cfgridcolumn name="Modify"
        header="Modified By"
        width=50
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="No"
        select="No">

    <cfgridcolumn name="Modify_Date"
        header="Modified Date"
        width=60
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="Yes"
        select="No"
        type="date">

    <cfgridcolumn name="PID_USED"
        header="Inventory<br>Instances"
        width=50
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="No"
        select="No">    

    <cfgridcolumn name="Inventory_Sum"
        header="Inventory<br>Total"
        width=50
        headeralign="center"
        headerbold="No"
        select="No">    
  </cfgrid>
```

the section from functions_pids.cfc

```
<cffunction name="updatePID" access="remote" output="false">

    <cfargument name="cfgridaction">
    <cfargument name="cfgridrow">
    <cfargument name="cfgridchanged">         
    <cfargument name="getcurruser"> <!--- pass in modified by user id --->
    <cfargument name="PID_ID" required="no" type="string" default="" >

    <cfset strctKey=StructKeyArray(cfgridchanged) />
    <cfset strctVal=StructFindKey(cfgridchanged, strctKey[1]) />
    <cfset strctVal=strctVal[1] />  


 <cfif cfgridaction is "D"> 

 <cfelseif cfgridaction is "U"> 

    <cfquery name="update" datasource="#request.dbname#" username="#request.dbuser#" password="#request.dbpw#">
      UPDATE PIDS
      SET #strctKey[1]# = '#strctVal.value#',
      Modify = '#getcurruser#',
      Modify_Date =  '#dateformat(CreateODBCDateTime( Now()), "mm/dd/yyyy")#'
      WHERE PID_ID = '#cfgridrow.PID_ID#'
    </cfquery>

  <cfelseif cfgridaction is "I"> 

  </cfif>
   <cfreturn />
 </cffunction>
```

Comment: Which update did you apply when this broke? I know Adobe just released another update a couple of days ago. That update includes some changes for CFGrid as well as AJAX functionality. [Bugs fixed in ColdFusion (2016 release) Update 5](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/bugs-fixed-coldfusion-2016-update-5.html#bugsfixed)

Comment: Miguel - update 5 was recently applied and resolved the issue

Comment: Great! Glad that fixed it for you. I will add that as an answer so other people will see it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

*Promoted from the comments*

Which update did you apply when this broke? I know Adobe just released another update a couple of days ago - Update 5. That update includes some changes for CFGrid as well as AJAX functionality. [Bugs fixed in ColdFusion (2016 release) Update 5](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/bugs-fixed-coldfusion-2016-update-5.html#bugsfixed)

> Bugs fixed in ColdFusion (2016 release) Update 5
>
> ```
> Bug ID        Description                                         Component
> CF-4198947    CFGrid scripting options do not work as expected.   AJAX : UI Components
>
> CF-4198855    cfquery requests result in the following error message:
>               Access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" 
>               "C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\classes\macromedia\sqlserverutil\userDefaults.properties" "read") Database
>
> CF-4198854    A piechart does not get displayed with only one item (100%).    Charting/Graphing
>
> CF-4198761    On a Linux OS, cfdocument does not generate chart in a pdf. Document Management : PDF generation
>
> CF-4198817    cfquery returns cached results even when the cachedafter date is updated to be after the date of the original cached query date, but is still a past date.  Database : CFQuery
>
> CF-4198816    Changes to cached query results are persisted back into cache.  Database : CFQuery
>
> CF-4198764    When loading the template for the first time, the template displays the CFTOKEN, however, with the second refresh the token disappears. Core Runtime : Session Management
>
> CF-4198589    Method invocation through ajaxproxy fails even if the required arguments are passed.    AJAX : Plumbing
>
> CF-4198570    The datefield attribute in cfinput does not display the value of the attribute. CFForm : HTML
>
> CF-4198559    The Elvis operator fails when used with argument scope. Core Runtime
>
> CF-4198513    The cache does not get updated as expected. Caching
>
> CF-4195407    cfinput type="datefield" generates invalid HTML code.   CFForm
>
> CF-4182090    When Sandbox security is enabled, you are unable to connect to SQL Server.  Security
> ```